# how to display value of textbox on same screen in android application just like whatsaap

Tags: android, whatsapp

This is my main file where i am calling the click event on button to pass the value.

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setTitle("aakash");

          SetContentView(R.id.lst);

          Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);
          b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(View.this,View.class));    
            }
        });   
    }


**xml**
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="aakash"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
    />

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/lst"
        android:background="#fefefe"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_holder"
        >



    </ScrollView>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chattxt"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:hint="type here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"

        android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want the value of textbox to display on the same screen(scrollview)box and also i want to pass a httppost request to pass a value..plz help me out

Thnks in advance

Comment: care for some clarity? please. From what i understand, i guess you are trying to enter what ever has been entered in your edit text to be placed in your scroll view. If that is what you need, i guess you should go through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html first.ScrollView SHOULD contain one view within it! ScrollVIew by itself is NOT a text view.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, a site for professional and enthusiastic programmers. As such, some additional detail are useful. Can you show some of your effort? What methods did you already found on your own that could be relevant? In which ways were these not sufficient: What exactly do you need? Secondly, please post separate questions as such, instead of stacking them into the same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer to my question

```
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);


    }
     public void setText(){
            Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            final EditText myInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    myText.setText(myInput.getText()); 
                }
            });    
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use a `ListView` insted of scroll view. and add list items from the chat text value dynamically.
call `notifydatasetchanged()` every time when you add a new item to it.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="aakash"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
/>

<ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView_chats"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                >
            </ListView>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/chattxt"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:hint="type here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"

    android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Write a custom adapter for the listView and add the code to manage the list data.

Comment: If you want the scrollview itself, then you might need to dynamically add textview to a LinearLayout lies inside the scrollview

Comment: I am using the custom adptr for this, its is my secnd screen where chat is possible where we enter the text and display on the screen ,actully i m not able to get the display of next on the same screen ,i am able to post this text on next screen ...Hope u getting what i am trying to ask